# SQL Function for Storing Point to Point Distance

Tags: sql, function, t-sql

I am trying to create a SQL function that will store the number of miles from a selected point to another point based on the mileage in my Distance table.  I am not familiar with creating functions but the code below is what I have pieced together so far:

---

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetMiles(@StartLoc VARCHAR, @DestLoc VARCHAR)
RETURNS DECIMAL
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @Miles DECIMAL

SELECT *
FROM 
(
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT Loc1, Loc2, Miles
    FROM Distance
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Loc2, Loc1, Miles
    FROM Distance
    ) AS t1
 )
  t1 
WHERE Loc1 = @StartLoc

INTERSECT

SELECT * 
FROM
(
    SELECT Loc1, Loc2, Miles
    FROM Distance
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Loc2, Loc1, Miles
    FROM Distance
    ) AS t2

WHERE Loc2 = @DestLoc

RETURN @Miles
END
```

---

When I run the code I get the following error message:

Msg 444, Level 16, State 2, Procedure GetMiles, Line 7 [Batch Start Line 0]

### Select statements included within a function cannot return data to a client.

Can someone help me with the code so that I can get the @Miles result so I can reference the result and store it another table for a user record?

Btw, I have tested all the code in the SELECT area and it does return the correct data with I put data for the variables.

Comment: the error is clear you are trying to return `SELECT` and no where you set a value for `@Miles`

Answer (score 1):

Your (quite strange) select potentially returns many rows with many fields without any assignment, meaning that the *results set* generated by the select would be returned by the function; this contradicts the specification of the function which is defined to return a single decimal number, `@Miles`. Besides that, the variable used to return the value is never given any value at all.

I suggest that you first review your select (I don't quite understand why it is like that) and then make sure that you assign a **single decimal value** to @Miles before the return statement.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do.  I want to assign the value to @Miles.  I am new to SQL coding and trying to figure out the best way to get value stored using this function.

Comment: OK ok... First, try your select manually till it returns a single numerical value (you need to work directly vis-à-vis the DB; I guess you are talking about SQL Server, so you need Management Studio; if not, specify your DBMS). Once you achieved that, you can use `SET @Miles = (SELECT ....);`, which will assign the result returned by the select to your variable `@Miles`. There are alternative syntaxes that can be used. Check the documentation.

Comment: I added    SET @Miles = (SELECT ....)    to my code and I get the error message:  "Must declare the scalar variable "@MILES"."  I am going to attempt to better explain what I'm trying to accomplish.  I have a table "Distance" that contains 3 fields (Loc1, Loc2, Miles)  one of the rows has   Loc1=Admin, Loc2=Blanton, Miles=4.3   so when the select statement above runs in SSMS (replacing StartLoc with 'Admin' and DestLoc with 'Blanton' or vice versa) it produces the record described as the result of the query.  I need a way to store the 4.3 miles in the user's record table for that trip entry.

Comment: Well, your explanation (the need) is quite clear and appears to be simple, in contrast to the query you presented in your question. As per the error message, it means that the declaration of the variable (i.e. the `DECLARE @Miles DECIMAL`) that you did include in your original question) is now somehow missing.

Comment: I just ran the original query shown in my original post again and I get the following error message:   Msg 444, Level 16, State 2, Procedure GetMiles, Line 6 [Batch Start Line 0]
Select statements included within a function cannot return data to a client.

Comment: This means that you are not **collecting** the results of the select into any local variable. What you want to return is a single value that you are named `@Miles` (and which, in your code, does not receive any value through an assignment of any kind). Please check the documentation on how to get the result of a select into a variable. Also, make sure that your select returns **ONE AND ONLY ONE** value.